# How to run commands inside the root session in python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, automation, root, pexpect

I have to implement a scenario where I need to login as root and then perform some ssh and scp commands through python to automate certain workflows.

**Example**: Suppose `MACHINE12` is my host and current user is `test`, i.e `test@MACHINE12`
I want a interactive code to be written in such a way that , if I put the following commands it should login as root user and the session should be maintained to perform other operations in `python`.

`{test@MACHINE12} su`

`password:`

once password is entered, logged in as root.

`{test@MACHINE12 test}`

Perform other commands here

`{test@MACHINE12 test} ssh user1@abc`

I tried this using the `pexpect` command in python, but the root session is not maintained or staying to perform other operations.
The commands can be only executed if the logged in session is root because `abc` host need `root` permission.

Find my tried snippet here:

```
def loginAsroot():
    childTab = pexpect.spawn("su") //command su to enter to root
    childTab.expect(":")
    childTab.sendline("asdgfgh")  // entering password
    childTab.expect("#")

def runCommands():
    command = "ssh user1@abc 'cat /dfg/hello.txt'>> /doc/g/auth.txt"
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, error = process.communicate(timeout=10000)
    return output

//function call
loginAsroot()
runCommands()
```

I'am trying to do linux command execution it is giving permission denied error, because the root session is not staying, its getting logged out. Hence `Permission denied`

How can I achieve this kind of executions?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use both pexpect and subprocess. These are possibly spawning different sessions. Does the following work?

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('su')
child.expect(':')
child.sendline('asdgfgh')
child.expect('#')
command = "ssh user1@abc 'cat /dfg/hello.txt'>> /doc/g/auth.txt"
child.sendline(command)
child.expect('#')
```

I think using either of the modules throughout would solve your issue.

Comment: I tried this, but it didnt work.

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

For SSH, I like **Paramiko**, because it takes care of overhead. To demonstrate, I wrote two versions of the code: one using Pexpect all the way, and the other using Paramiko. Just remember:

1. Make sure the IP address of the remote machine is not in the `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`; otherwise you get the `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` error.
2. I prefer [expect_exact](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect_exact) because [expect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect) uses regex patterns. With `expect`, you can get an error if you look for a prompts that use regex characters, such as `$`.
3. I also prefer using `su -` over `su` if I have to use `root`, since it clears the environment variables.

Thanks for the question, by the way. Sometimes I forget what I just told you to remember :facepalm: !

> **NOTE** - Tested using two Debian VM's and Python 3.9. I changed the prompts and obscured the passwords and IP addresses.

**Using Pexpect (with everything echoed to STDOUT):**

```
import sys

import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("su -", logfile=sys.stdout.buffer)
child.expect_exact("Password:")
child.sendline("**********")
child.expect_exact("#")
child.sendline("ssh user@192.168.X.X")
while True:
    # Must use expect_exact to avoid expect regex conflict with prompt ($)!
    index = child.expect_exact(
        ["Are you sure you want to continue connecting", "password:", "$", ])
    if index == 0:
        child.sendline("yes")
    elif index == 1:
        child.sendline("**********")
    else:
        break
child.sendline("cat hello.txt >> auth.txt")
child.expect_exact("$")
child.sendline("cat auth.txt")
child.expect_exact("$")
# If you do not use the logfile, you can make sure the file got copied using:
# print(child.before)
child.sendline("exit")
child.expect_exact("#")
child.sendline("exit")
# The child closes after the exit command (EOF); this is just to make sure
child.expect_exact(["$", pexpect.EOF, ])
child.close()
print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output:**

```
Password: **********

test@MACHINE12:~# ssh user1@192.168.X.X
ssh user1@192.168.X.X
The authenticity of host '192.168.X.X (192.168.X.X)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:********************************************
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.X.X' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
**********@192.168.X.X's password: **********

Last login: Sat Dec  4 20:40:12 2021 from 192.168.X.X
user1@192.168.X.X:~$ cat hello.txt >> auth.txt
cat hello.txt >> auth.txt
user1@192.168.X.X:~$ cat auth.txt
cat auth.txt
Hello, world!
user1@192.168.X.X:~$ b' cat auth.txt\r\nHello, world!\r\nuser1@192.168.X.X:~'
exit
exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.X.X closed.

test@MACHINE12:~# exit
exit
Script complete. Have a nice day.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Using Paramiko (without echoing):**

```
import paramiko
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("su -")
child.expect_exact("Password:")
child.sendline("**********")
child.expect_exact("#")
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("192.168.X.X", username="user1", password="**********")
ssh.exec_command("cat hello.txt >> auth.txt")
_, chan_out, _ = ssh.exec_command("cat auth.txt")
print("\nauth contents:", chan_out.read().decode())
ssh.close()
child.sendline("exit")
child.expect_exact(["$", pexpect.EOF, ])
child.close()
print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output:**

`auth contents: Hello, world!`

Good luck with your code!